# Spanish Analyser with lucene

Tags: lucene

Analyser need an implementation of Spanish. If anyone knows where I can get, I appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Analyser of what? Do you mean an implementation of Lucene's `Analyzer` class for Spanish?

You may want to take a look at [Snowball](http://snowball.tartarus.org/). It appears as though the Snowball word stemmer supports Spanish and can be integrated with Lucene.

Comment: oops,  my mistake, do not use Google  Translate, so that you could  even parse my question.  Thanks for your support collaborative.

Answer (score 2):

Analyzer analyzer = new SnowballAnalyzer("Spanish");

Snowball is in lucene/contrib/snowball

Here are answers: http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/xJxT8iJf07j8mdQwgHyu